# how to prevent duplicate username on signup page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 pages login and signup. and i am checking whether the username is available or not.and i have written a code  for it.but i can not prevent inserting of same username in database on signup button. How can I do that?

here is my code on signup `page`. I have taken one `linkbutton` on sign up page-

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from login where username='" + txtname.Text + "'", conn);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Label1.Text = "Username already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Username available";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are inviting anonymous users for sql-injection. Use sql-parameters instead. Or even better - have a look at the available `SqlMembershipProvider`. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: quick and dirty: in your database, create a unique constraint on *username* column.

Comment: Make use of flag(boolean variable) in your database

Answer (score 2):

You should use `MembershipProvider` class built in asp.net

still if you want to stick with your code then
use `IF(EXISTS)` in your query

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserMaster WHERE LOWER(UserName) = LOWER('test')))
BEGIN
    SELECT 'TRUE'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'FALSE'
END
```

and then finally use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` function to check whether returned value is `true` or `false`

**C# Code:**(updated)

```
    conn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@" IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UserMaster WHERE LOWER(UserName) = LOWER(@username)))
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'TRUE'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'FALSE'
    END", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "test");
    bool exists = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    if (exists)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Username already exists";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Username available";
    }
```

Comment: Just make sure you parameterize `UserName`.